# Ruby on Rails: How to structure a has_many, through association when join model uses a belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to create a has_many, through association when the join model uses a belongs_to.

Example here:

```
class User
  has_many :projects, through: :project_memberships
end

class ProjectMembership
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project
  has_many :project_memberships
end
```

Rails is telling me this association is invalid. If it's not possible to use a `:through` association here, what's the best way to use ActiveRecord to access all projects a user has memberships to?

Answer (score 3):

User must be related to `ProjectMembership`, for example:

```
class User
  has_many :project_memberships
  has_many :projects, through: :project_memberships
end

class ProjectMembership
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end

class Project
  has_many :project_memberships
end
```

Check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for more information on associations.

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...NER JOIN "project_memberships" ON "projects"."id" = "project...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "project_memberships" ON "projects"."id" = "project_memberships"."project_id" WHERE "project_memberships"."user_id" = $1

Comment: This is the error I'm getting with my updated code. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Figured it out. I had my ID's stored as strings (whoops!). Thanks for the help